# Opening HTML file in web browser in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

When I right-click on my html doc and select `open with web browser`, the browser opens, but shows no content. My other HTML docs in other projects work just fine, but for some reason, this will not display anything. Any suggestions?

[image: HTML Doc]

Comment: Is that the Source Code? JavaScript can render HTML on the Client, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page doesn't actually have any **content**, hence why you are not seeing any. HTML written in the **[`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)** section is not rendered on the page, but rather is used to load external files and hold metadata. The **[`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)** section is what gets written to the page itself:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Not visible</title>
</head>

<body>
  Visible!
</body>

</html>
```

The **[`<title>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title)** element simply sets the name that is shown in the **tab**. If you want to create a title on the page itself, you're probably looking to create an **[`<h1>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/h1)** element (as you've already created some styling for such an element).

Hope this helps! :)